# LyX Layout File for the SIAM book class

Tags: lyx

Is there a LyX layout file for the SIAM book (SIAM-GH-book.cls) class?

Comment: Perhaps there is a class for `LaTeX` that you can use in `LyX`. Take a look at the [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siam) there is something that you can find useful.

Comment: Thanks Aradnix. I have had a look a the CTAN. I was not able to find a LyX layout file there. I have to search elsewhere to find the layout file if it exists. Thanks once more.

Comment: Well LyX uses all the `texaware` below so perhaps you can use that CTAN package over `LyX`.